# Como inserir imagens no Android Studio a partir de uma pasta drawable?

Tags: android, sqlite

Pessoal gostaria de saber se é possível carregar uma imagem a partir de uma pasta drawable. Por exemplo, tenho um ListView com várias categorias, quando uma categoria for selecionada gostaria que aparecesse todas as imagens relacionadas a esta categoria, e assim o usuário possa acessa-las. Mas não sei com fazer isso. Pensei em adicionar todas as imagens em pastas na drawable e assim inserir no banco e fazer um select para apresentar estas categorias.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findById(R.id.imagemXml);
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagem1);
```

Mas é melhor prática salvar na verdade o link para a imagem no banco de dados(melhor ainda: salvar o link num banco externo), e não a imagem na pasta drawable...
Aí você carrega o link e o usuário vai fazer download da imagem.
Aconselho o uso da biblioteca [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) para fazer isso automaticamente.

Fica: `Glide.with(this).load("www.imagem.com.br/img1").into(imageview)`
No load pode também colocar imagens da drawable.
Fica: `Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.imagem1).into(imageview)`

Você pode ainda fazer um array de int e comportar todas as imagens da pasta drawable(porque R.drawable.img é int) e salvar no banco somente a posição desse array...
na Posição 10 é a imagem de uma girafa...então, toda vez que o programa abre, o array é carregado e na posição 10 que o banco retornou estará a imagem da girafa...aí pega simplesmente como arrayDeImagens[10]...Fica: `Glide.with(this).load(arrayDeImagens[10]).into(imageview)`

Comment: Obrigado! Vou pesquisar sobre a biblioteca Glide.